# Matrix norms and partitioning

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

ON a practice exam http://math.berkeley.edu/~mgu/MA128B2012S/SampleMidTerm.pdf

I am unsure how we can begin #4. I know the definition of the matrix norm and the infinity norm, but they dont seem to work in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $1$-norm, not infinity norm. It is defined by $\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$. Note that
$$
\|A\|_{2,1}=\max\limits_{\sum\limits_i |x_i|=1}\|\sum_i x_ia_i\|_2.
$$
By triangle inequality, for every vector $x$ such that $\|x\|_1=1$,
\begin{equation}
\|\sum_i x_ia_i\|_2\le\sum_i \|x_ia_i\|_2=\sum_i |x_i|\|a_i\|_2
\color{red}{\le}\sum_i |x_i|\max_j\|a_j\|_2=\max_{1\le j\le n}\|a_j\|_2.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Taking maximum over all $x$ with unit $1$-norm, we get $\|A\|_{2,1}\le\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\|a_j\|_2$. Now, show that there is a vector $x$ such that $\|x\|_1=1$ and equality in $(1)$ holds. (When does equality hold for the red inequality above?)

Comment: Can you put those details here?

Comment: @mary Partially done. I'll leave the last step to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this problem is that

$$
\|A\|_{2,1} = \max_{\|x\|_1=1}\|Ax\|_2.
$$

In other words, we're taking the largest vector that we get when we take all convex combinations (positive linear combinations where the coefficients sum to $1$) of the columns of $A$.

Suppose that we take the column with the largest norm ($a_j$). Then if we take a convex combination of $a_j$ with any other column, then the norm is decreased, because the combination lies on the line segment between $a_j$ and the other column.

Therefore

$$
\|A\|_{2,1} = \max_{1\leq j\leq n}\|a_j\|_2.
$$